# How to implement a command list for multiple users?

Tags: c#, .net, roles, user-permissions, restriction

I have a list of commands, for example:

- **command1**, **command2**, **test**, **exit**

I also have users:

- *admin*, *user1*, *user2*

The goal is to make it possible for users to invoke commands that are available to them.
For example,

- *admin* - **command1**, **command2**, **test**, **exit**
- *user1* - **command1**, **test**
- *user2* - **command2**

What is the best way to implement this if I have two variables at the input - the **commandName** and **userName**.

This is currently done on switch, but it’s very inconvenient for scaling project.

Comment: Your question has a low quality or what you asking for is unclear or too broad. What is your goal? What is your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your dev environment and share more code or some screenshot of your screeen. To help you improve the content, title and tags of your query, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* which is in the help center.

Comment: @OlivierRogier It seemed to me that I clearly explained. Thanks for the link. I have already received the good answers and am working on their implementation. When I finish the implementation and there are no questions, I will send out my solution and mark the answers as accepted.

Comment: It seemed perhaps to you that you clearly explained. Some have understood, but you do not say what you are talking about. You did not indicate any tags. We do not know what you're talking about. Personally, I thought you were talking about sql commands and you wanted to manage database access autorisatrions. And you provide no code that can indicate what you want to do nor what you have tried. So your question is unclear. So reading the answers you say matching your request, it becomes clear now, but your question is not a problem of programming. Your question is not about C# in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create list of dictionaries with commands and user access to commands (or the similar one into DB):

```
 var commandList = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
            commandList.Add("command1", () => { Console.WriteLine("command1 is executed"); });
            commandList.Add("command2", () => { Console.WriteLine("command2 is executed"); });
            commandList.Add("command3", () => { Console.WriteLine("command3 is executed"); });
            var listOfUserCommands = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            listOfUserCommands.Add("user1", new List<string>() { "command1" });
            listOfUserCommands.Add("user2", new List<string>() { "command2", "command3" });

            var userName = "user1";
            var commandName = "command2";
            if (listOfUserCommands.ContainsKey(userName) && listOfUserCommands[userName].Contains(commandName))
            {
                commandList[commandName]();
            }
```

it might be modified for using command Aliases:

```
public interface IExecutionCommand
    {
        Action Action { set; get;}
        List<string> Aliases { set; get; }

    }
    public class ExecutionCommand1: IExecutionCommand
    {
        public Action Action { set; get; }
        public List<string> Aliases { set; get; }
        public ExecutionCommand1()
        {
            Action = () => { Console.WriteLine("command1 is executed"); };
            Aliases = new List<string>() { "cmd1" };
        }
    }
    public class ExecutionCommand2: IExecutionCommand
    {
        public Action Action { set; get; }
        public List<string> Aliases { set; get; }
        public ExecutionCommand2()
        {
            Action = () => { Console.WriteLine("command2 is executed"); };
            Aliases = new List<string>() { "cmd2" };
        }
    }
    public class ExecutionCommand3: IExecutionCommand
    {
        public Action Action { set; get; }
        public List<string> Aliases { set; get; }
        public ExecutionCommand3()
        {
            Action = () => { Console.WriteLine("command3 is executed"); };
            Aliases = new List<string>() { "cmd3" };
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        //_startScanning();
        var commandList = new List<IExecutionCommand>();
        commandList.Add(new ExecutionCommand1());
        commandList.Add(new ExecutionCommand2());
        commandList.Add(new ExecutionCommand3());
        var listOfUserCommands = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        listOfUserCommands.Add("user1", new List<string>() { "cmd2" });
        listOfUserCommands.Add("user2", new List<string>() { "command1", "command3" });

        var userName = "user1";
        var commandName = "cmd2";

        if (listOfUserCommands.ContainsKey(userName) && listOfUserCommands[userName].Contains(commandName))
        {
            IExecutionCommand command = commandList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Aliases.Contains(commandName));
            command?.Action();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking of such an implementation. Thanks for the nice sample code!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make alias for a command? For example test -> check. Just add alias like a command where name is alias and call the same method or is there another way?

Comment: I have added solution without command dictionary and  with command aliases

Answer (score 3):

#### Your solution is permissions.

1. Create roles and assign set of permissions to them;
2. Assign roles to your users and create ability to include additional permissions for specific users;
3. Split your command handlers into different methods (no switches!) and check the permission in the start of your command execution.

#### Here's a pseudocode how I think command handler should look like:

```
public ExecutionResult ExecuteCommand1(User user, string[] arguments) {
   if(!user.HasPermission("admin.test.permission")) {
       return new ExecutionResult() {
           Error = true,
           Message = "You don't have permissions to execute that command!"
       };
   }

   user.GiveKarma(1337);

   return new ExecutionResult {
       Message = "Karma points were added!"
   };
}
```

#### Permission indentifiers shouldn't be strings as in my example code.

You can use anything: string, enums, etc.

Comment: My command handlers are separated by methods, I just call them in Switch. My commandName and userName are String. About the roles - 1 user 1 role. I was thinking of a list similar to KeyValue - {commandName, commandMethod}
And the list is {userName, availableCommands}, but it seems to me that this is also not a good solution.

Comment: Permissions system isn't that bad.. Custom Minecraft servers are using them, ejabberd server is using them.

Comment: TeamSpeak also uses permissions. This method looks good. Thanks.

Comment: @Des1re Note that the [stringly typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) approach with using string literals (`"admin.test.permission"`) is liable to become debugging hell as it's easy to make a mistake and is not refactor friendly. If you take this route, go strongly typed. At the very least, declare constants for your users/commands so you can keep the code refactor friendly.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I got following to the example of Oleg Bondarenko. The solution is not perfect, but suddenly someone will be need it.

```
Dictionary<string, List<IExecutionCommand>> listOfUserCommands = new Dictionary<string, List<IExecutionCommand>>();

public interface IExecutionCommand
{
    Action Action { set; get; }
    List<string> Aliases { set; get; }
}

public class commandTest : IExecutionCommand
{
    public Action Action { set; get; }
    public List<string> Aliases { set; get; }
    public commandTest()
    {
        Action = () => { Console.WriteLine("command1 is executed"); };
        Aliases = new List<string>() { "test", "check", "tests" };
    }
}
public class commandEx2 : IExecutionCommand
{
    public Action Action { set; get; }
    public List<string> Aliases { set; get; }
    public commandEx2()
    {
        Action = () => { Console.WriteLine("command2 is executed"); };
        Aliases = new List<string>() { "cmd2" };
    }
}


private IExecutionCommand FindingCommandFromUser(string commandName, List<IExecutionCommand> commandList)
{
    foreach (IExecutionCommand command in commandList)
        if (command.Aliases.Contains(commandName))
            return command;
    return null;
}

public static void Main()
{
    listOfUserCommands.Add("user1",
                            new List<IExecutionCommand>()
                            {
                                    new commandTest(),
                                    new commandEx2()
                            });

    string userName = "user1";
    string commandName = "check";

    IExecutionCommand curCommand = null;

    if (listOfUserCommands.ContainsKey(userName) && ((curCommand = FindingCommandFromUser(commandName, listOfUserCommands[userName])) != null))
        curCommand.Action();
}
```

Comment: You could just define name (aliases) of associated commands with user not whole commands and find them by name  ` var command = commandList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Aliases.Contains(commandName))` .

Comment: Can you please explain how your expression works? I understand that it replaces my FindingCommandFromUser? I don’t understand why FirstOrDefault?

Comment: There might be not single command with search name in command collection or otherwise not presented at all. In first case expression gets first found one and in second case  result  will be null. FirstOrDefault with condition  is equal the pair of  `where` expresiion and `FirstOrDefault()` without params. There is good examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: My gratitude knows no bounds! Now I understand how lambda expressions work. It was a useful experience and I don’t know how I lived without them.

Comment: True, Linq is very usuful tool in c#. I am glad that I could help